# Is there a way that I can give the user feedback when the click on an element that has a gesture recogniser?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

When my users click on links on the app I would like to give them some feedback. I think it's called something like haptic feedback. Is it possible to do this in iOS and Android with Xamarin forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [Vibrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/vibrate?tabs=android) plugin

```
var duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
Vibration.Vibrate(duration);
```